# FreeSwitch/FusionPBX Transfers to the Wrong Extension

Tags: freeswitch

Here is my scenario:

A caller makes a call to PSTN line which is connected to GrandStream GWX4108, registered as a freeswitch gateway.

1. Phone is picked by an IVR--Welcome IVR (Exten: 5000).
2. Caller pressed 1, transferred to another IVR--MainMenu-IVR-NP (Exten: 5001).
3. Caller pressed 0, transferred to Hunt Group--FrontDesk Hunt. (Exten: 6500).
4. An operator of the FrontDesk Hunt at extension 6002 picks up the call. She then performs a blind transfer to the extension 9999.

The extension 9999 does not ring. To my surprise, the call goes to another Hunt Group--Support Hunt (Exten 6600).

Below is a copy of the log for investigation and review.

http://pastebin.com/vZ2z6bUH

**EDIT #1**

Except for the above problem, all the extensions are working normally. For example, for outgoing calls originating from any extension, we can transfer the call to any extension without any problem.

**Edit #2**

**Dialplan of Exten 9999**

/directory/default/v_9999.xml

```
<include>
  <user id="9999">
    <params>
      <param name="password" value="secret"/>
      <param name="vm-password" value="user-choose"/>
      <param name="vm-enabled" value="true"/>
    </params>
    <variables>
      <variable name="toll_allow" value=""/>
      <variable name="accountcode" value=""/>
      <variable name="user_context" value="default"/>
      <variable name="effective_caller_id_name" value="CEO Line2"/>
      <variable name="directory-visible" value="true"/>
      <variable name="directory-exten-visible" value="true"/>
      <variable name="limit_max" value="5"/>
    </variables>
  </user>
</include>
```

Comment: Looking at the log I cant see any sip activity related to 9999, just dialplan messages, so i guess your problem is in your dialplan. Please double check 9999 at default context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionPBX-->Dialplan-->Dialplan Manager

Edit the dialplan "extension-intercom", set enabled to true.

We had the similar issue which was solved by setting the above parameter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your log you are calling not the directory user 9999 but the xml dialplan extension 9999:

> 2012-08-25 20:11:15.575195 [NOTICE] switch_ivr.c:1711 Transfer
>   sofia/internal/9851187087@192.168.0.200 to XML[9999@default]

Please add to your dialplan/default.xml:

```
<context name="default">
  <extension name="9999">
     <condition field="destination_number" expression="9999">
        <action application="bridge" data="user/9999"/> 
     </condition>
  </extension>
</context>
```

Or change your dialplan to redirect to user/9999 instead.

Comment: Could you provide your dialplan?